# Django -> django.db.backends DEBUG enabled keep printing (%.3f) %s; args=%s

Tags: python, django

When I set the logger level to DEBUG on django.db.backends it keeps printing this message

```
[14/Jun/2019 18:47:53] [DEBUG] [django.db.backends -> utils.py -> execute -> 90 -> (%.3f) %s; args=%s]
[14/Jun/2019 18:47:53] [DEBUG] [django.db.backends -> utils.py -> execute -> 90 -> (%.3f) %s; args=%s]
[14/Jun/2019 18:47:53] [DEBUG] [django.db.backends -> utils.py -> execute -> 90 -> (%.3f) %s; args=%s]
[14/Jun/2019 18:47:53] [DEBUG] [django.db.backends -> utils.py -> execute -> 90 -> (%.3f) %s; args=%s]
[14/Jun/2019 18:47:53] [DEBUG] [django.db.backends -> utils.py -> execute -> 90 -> (%.3f) %s; args=%s]
```

My logger format is

```
'format' : "[%(asctime)s] [%(levelname)s] [%(name)s -> %(filename)s -> %(funcName)s -> %(lineno)s -> %(msg)s]",
```

Python version 3.7
Django version 1.11.20

Any idea what this is about ?

Answer (score 0):

Python logging default doesn't support unicode.
In Django settings, Add 'encoding': 'utf-8' to logging handlers.

```
LOGGING = {
    ...
    'handlers': {
        'django_log_file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': join(LOGFILE_ROOT, 'django.log'),
            'encoding': 'utf-8',    # <-- Add this 
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        },
    ...  
}
```